# How to buffer the extreme value of f(x) to draw a line representing a range of f(x)?

Tags: pstricks, best-practices, programming, pst-plot, code-review

Please consider the following animation.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f{x^2-x-6}
\psset{unit=3,algebraic}

\def\Atom#1{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-6.5)(2,-2.5)
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-1}{1}{\f}
    \psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=5\pslinewidth](-1,-3.5)(#1,-3.5)
    \psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=5\pslinewidth](0,0|*-1 {\f})(0,0|*#1 {\f})
    \psline[linecolor=orange,linestyle=dashed](#1,-3.5)(*#1 {\f})(0,0|*#1 {\f})
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](*#1 {\f}){2pt}
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray,Oy=-3.50,Dy=.25,Dx=.5]{->}(0,-3.5)(-1.49,-6.49)(1.5,-3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\r=-1.0+.125}{17}{\Atom{\r}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The vertical green line is supposed to be a range of `f(x)` in `-1<=x<=1`. When `x>.5` I want to prevent the vertical green line (range) from shrinking. My rough idea is as follows, but it will not compile as `\ifnum` cannot be a fraction.

```
\ifnum#1>.5
    \psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=5\pslinewidth](0,0|*-1 {\f})(0,0|*.5 {\f})
\else
    \psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=5\pslinewidth](0,0|*-1 {\f})(0,0|*#1 {\f})
\fi
```

Actually `fp` package can help but I want to avoid using it. In order to accommodate more general function, I want to buffer the minimum value of `f(x)` for each iteration in `-1<=x<=1` and use this buffer against which the current value of `\f` is compared.

What do you think?

Comment: I can also change the `#1` to be an integer and manipulate it in the point expression `(*{#1 ... 8 div} {\f})` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\ifdim` to check for double numbers:

```
\ifdim#1pt>.5pt
    \psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=5\pslinewidth](0,0|*-1 {\f})(0,0|*.5 {\f})
\else
    \psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=5\pslinewidth](0,0|*-1 {\f})(0,0|*#1 {\f})
\fi
```

If you want to have it very flexible, you need to accumulate all previous function values. First I tried to save with `\pnode` the current minimum value, but that doesn't work because you images span over several pages. So you can accumulate the Postscript code of all function values and the determine the minimum when you need it for `\psline`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-plot}
\def\f{x^2-x-6}
\psset{unit=3,algebraic}

\makeatletter
\def\minynode@list{}%
\def\addyvalue(#1){%
  \pst@getcoor{#1}\pst@tempA%
  \ifx\minynode@list\@empty
    \xdef\minynode@list{mark }%
  \fi
  \xdef\minynode@list{\minynode@list \pst@tempA \tx@UserCoor exch pop }
}%
\def\getminyvalue{%
  \minynode@list counttomark 1 sub { min } repeat exch pop 0 exch 
}
\makeatother

\def\Atom#1{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-6.5)(2,-2.5)
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-1}{1}{\f}
    \psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=5\pslinewidth](-1,-3.5)(#1,-3.5)
    \addyvalue(0,0|*#1 {\f})
    \psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=5\pslinewidth](0,0|*-1 {\f})(!\getminyvalue)
    \psline[linecolor=orange,linestyle=dashed](#1,-3.5)(*#1 {\f})(0,0|*#1 {\f})
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](*#1 {\f}){2pt}
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray,Oy=-3.50,Dy=.25,Dx=.5]{->}(0,-3.5)(-1.49,-6.49)(1.5,-3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\r=-1.0+.125}{17}{\Atom{\r}}
\end{document}
```

That works, but I'm open for improvements :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\psline[linecolor=green,linewidth=5\pslinewidth]%
       (0,0|*-1 {\f})(*{#1 .5 gt {.5}{#1} ifelse } {\f})
```

Comment: I don't understand why `pstricks` loads `pgffor` by default but does not load `multido`. I think `multido` should be loaded by default as well.